# Image Slideshow javascript

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I can't find out why my Image slideshow doesn't work on the webpage, Can someone tell me why?

I have the code below

```
<head>
 <script type ="text/javaScript">

      var image1=new Image()
      image1.src="download.jpg"
      var image2=new Image()
      image2.src="beauty.jpg"

</script> 
</head> 

<body>
<img src="download.jpg" name="firstImage" height = 100 width=300></img>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //variable that would increment through the images
      var step = 1  
      function slideit() {
        //if browser does not support the image object exit
        if(!document.images)
          return document.images.firstImage.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

        if(step<2) 
          step++
        else 
          step=1

        //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
        setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
      }
      slideit()
       </script>
  </html>
```

I have tried putting the whole javascript in one  tag but it doesn't really affect it, Can someone tell me what I may be missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think it doing nothing `if(step<2)  step++  else  step=1`

Comment: @user3766803 There are couple of issues here but do not worry... We are all here to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
      function slideit() {
       if(document.images)
       document.images.firstImage.src=eval("image"+step+".src");
       if(step<2) 
       step++
       else 
       step=1
       setTimeout(slideit,2500)
                         }
```

i have put your code here its working

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pS7N/1/)

The problem is if(!document.images) is gives always false so i just make it if(document.images) without this i dont change any of your code..

Comment: hi ! Changing to slideit instead of "slideit()" didn't work either, I didn't think it would since slideit() is a function, but I still double checked anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
    <html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <script type ="text/javaScript">

     var image1=new Image()
  image1.src="download.jpg"
  var image2=new Image()
  image2.src="beauty.jpg"

    </script> 
    </head> 

    <body>
    <img src="globe/images/correct.png" name="firstImage" height = 100 width=300></img>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //variable that would increment through the images
    var step = 1  
    function slideit() {


    if(step<2) 
    step++
    else 
    step=1

    document.images.firstImage.src=window["image"+step].src;



    //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout(slideit,2500)
    }
    slideit()
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I see you have included a png image in this line - <img src="globe/images/correct.png" --- whereas the images in Javascript are .jpg; and what is correct.png?

Comment: just use like this <img src="" name="firstImage" height = 100 width=300></img>

Comment: Having no img src leads to no image when i open up the webpage, I am unable to get the slide show working

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of slideshow you want. At background or at image slideshow in div? I mentioned here slideshows of various images using jquery. Try it hope it will be useful to you.

HTML code :

```
<div id="slide">
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/1.jpg"/>
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/4.jpg"/>
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/2.jpg"/>
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/3.jpg"/>
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/5.jpg"/> 
<img class="img-responsive disp" src="img/14.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#slide > img'), 
    current = 0;

    var nextImage = function() {
    if (current >= $imgs.length) current = 0;
    $imgs.eq(current++).fadeIn(function() {
    $(this).delay(800).fadeToggle(nextImage);
    })};
    nextImage();

    });
```

CSS :

```
.disp{display:none;}
```

This works for image slideshow on webpage.

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of issues - [Image Slideshow javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573097/image-slideshow-javascript#comment38063775_24573097) - version below is close to what you already have...

*(requires 0.png and 1.png in the directory)*

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head> 

  <body>
    <img src="1.png" name="firstImage" height=100 width=300>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 1;

    function slideit() {

      var imagenumber = step++ % 2;
      var imagesrc = imagenumber + ".png";
      document.images.firstImage.src = imagesrc;

      setTimeout(slideit,2500)
    }

    slideit()
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello ! Doing this doesn't display any image on my webpage, why did you think .png would work instead of .jpg?

Comment: ```.png``` and ```.jpg``` will work equally good, it was just easier for me to make screenshots that by default have ```.png``` extension. Please have a demo with ```.jpg``` here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sA42q7Cm94Jbc051yJjO?p=preview